# How to get content from a single *page* of a post?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to do a gallery sorta thing, split post to multiple pages and paginate them with jQuery. Has anyone tried something similar, could you help me with some guidelines to set it up?

Something like this and similar galleries on websites: http://hitfix.com/galleries/most-anticipated-tv-premieres-and-returns-of-2012

I've managed to make something similar, but without jQuery, and I know users get annoyed when site has to reload every time for each page.

edit:
**I'll add a followup question here:**

What function can I use to fetch content of a single page within a post?
Let's say I want to split my post to 5 pages - how can I get content of, say, page 3?

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of `slider`/`slideshow` plugins you can use for this but if you want to make it yourself then you can setup a navigation bar like the site you linked to and when one of the numbers is clicked you can make an AJAX call to a PHP script that outputs the desired information:

HTML--

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="page"></div>
```

CSS--

```
#navigation li {
    display : inline-block;

    /*Fix display:inline-block in IE7*/
    *display : inline;
    zoom     : 1;
}
```

jQuery--

```
$(function () {

    //cache the `#page` element as it will be needed later
    var $page = $('#page');

    //bind a `click` event handler to all the `<li>` elements that are children of the `#navigation` ul element
    $('#navigation').children().on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //you could display a loading animation/message here while the new content is being returned from the server

        //when making the AJAX call you need to send some data to identify the "page" to output, I used the `id` key and set it's value to the index of the `<li>` element clicked in respect to all the other `<li>`s
        $.get('path/to/server-side.php', { id : $(this).index() }, function (serverResponse) {

            //now set the `#page` element's HTML to the response from the server
            $page.html(serverResponse);

            //if you played a loading animation/message you can hide it now
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jGujw/ (Note that I could not test with an AJAX function so I stored some server responses in an array)

It is also possible to paginate by grabbing the same page over and over in the AJAX request and parsing the `serverReponse` to only append the desired elements into the DOM.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` if you are using an older version.

Comment: Thans mate. I was really pleasantly surprised surprised with that detailed answer. I have perhaps asked my question too broadly, I was seeking some guidlines how to do it at Wordpress side, but this has also helped since I haven't had much experience with jQuery (but have more than some with php and WP). Anyhow, my current problem is:
What function can I use to fetch content of a single page within a post? Let's say I want to split my post to 5 pages - how can I get content of, say, page 3?
May I ask this in new... thread / question, or is this considered as spamming?

Comment: @stackhouse You may want to mark Jasper's question as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Within the wordpress universe, you do have access to all of wordpress... but it's a matter of what you do to get that visibility. Below is a code snippet I used on a homepage to get the 3 most recent posts and display snippets of them. If you're outside the scope of wordpress, you need to find a way to include some wordpress files.

I believe what I've provided and some googling can get you sorted out... if `$myposts` has 3 post arrays as members, you can pick and choose.

```
<!-- language: php -->
<?  $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3');
        foreach($myposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);  ?>
<h2 id="page_title"><a class="noblock" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="ccw_light location"><small><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></small></p>
                        <br style="line-height:5px">
                        <div class="content_text" id="noblock">
                                <?php the_content('... continues','','') ?>
                                        <span class="right"><small>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> <strong>|</strong> <?php edit_post_link('Edit','','<strong> |</strong>'); ?></small>
                                        </span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
<br> <!-- <?php trackback_rdf(); ?> -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```